# JavaScript: Match a string to the name of an array rather than a variable held within the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, find, match

I am writing an algorithm that checks the answers of a puzzle using JavaScript. I have several arrays of similar names ex. col1, col2, col3. I would like to create a string variable and use it to find a matching array, where the string matches the name of the array. Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Comment: show your input array and a string

Comment: Use [json](http://www.json.org/) format

Comment: @anu _"JSON is a lightweight data-interchange format"_ I may have missed it, but where is Marie-Clare asking for a data-interchange format?

Comment: that [awnser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) could help you

Comment: @Andreas Well it was my assumption that OP must be loading the puzzles from some db and later verifying it. As the background of the problem is not stated I might be wrong, so just wanted to provide info just in case. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I Know this is incorrect but I have 9 arrays named col1-col9 i want to make an algorthim that will loop around each array consecutively.... something like this (except this is obviously wrong) :
function check()
{
    var type = col;
    for(i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        var arrayName = type + i;
        for (arrayName[])
        {

        }
    }
}

Comment: @Marie-ClareMurray How are you getting these arrays? From server as a response or are you creating it dynamically?